# Are both similar? Fourier Series question.

Tags: fourier-series

My professor gave two problems which are,

1) $f(x)=3x$ , $-L<x<L$  And $f(x+2L)=f(x)$

2) $f(x)=3x$ , $0<x<2L$  And $f(x+2L)=f(x)$

And we have to find the Fourier series of each function. We gotta find $a0$ , $an$ and $bn$ coefficients separately and combine those to get the series.

I'm quite confused because these two questions are same to me. I have poor knowledge of fourier series. So can someone explain are both give same answer or different answers.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the two functions? The two functions are different. For example, for the first function, $f(1.5L) = f(-0.5L) = 3(-0.5)L = -1.5L$. But for the second function, $f(1.5L) = 3(1.5)L = 4.5L$.

Comment: Instead of worrying your brain it's better to calculate the coefficients. :-)

Comment: But to solve that I don't know what should be the Half interval for both problems?